# RSpec tests failing for Rails 3.2.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

The RSpec test suite for my project https://github.com/phoet/on_ruby fails when updating Rails from 3.2.6 to 3.2.7.

```
rake spec
  1) Authorization should create an auth and a user from an auth-hash
     Failure/Error: Authorization.create_from_hash(auth)
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique:
       SQLite3::ConstraintException: column nickname is not unique: INSERT INTO "users" ("admin", "available", "created_at", "description", "freelancer", "github", "hide_jobs", "image", "location", "name", "nickname", "slug", "updated_at", "url") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
     # ./app/models/user.rb:74:in `create_from_hash!'
     # ./app/models/authorization.rb:15:in `create_from_hash'
     # ./spec/models/authorization_spec.rb:23:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/authorization_spec.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Google Geocoding API error: over query limit.                  | ETA:  00:00:03
  2) Location finder should find users within the default scope
     Failure/Error: Location.unscoped.all.size.should be(2)

       expected #<Fixnum:5> => 2
            got #<Fixnum:21> => 10

       Compared using equal?, which compares object identity,
       but expected and actual are not the same object. Use
       'actual.should eq(expected)' if you don't care about
       object identity in this example.
     # ./spec/models/location_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This problem does not occur when running RSpec directly, nor does it occur on travis: http://travis-ci.org/#!/phoet/on_ruby/builds/1989858

It looks as if the transactions do not rollback properly. Did someone experience a similar behavior?

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm getting the same.  From what I can tell, rails is now sets ENV['RAILS_ENV']=development, so your tests are running against you development database.   Try `rake spec RAILS_ENV=test`

It looks like it's this issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7175